# Adding several views to consecutive pages in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android application that uses a `ViewPager` widget that should represent a restaurant's menu. Every page should contain several item choices and titles, for example:

**Page 1:**

*Meat*

- meat type 1    price
- meat type 2    price
- the rest...
- meat type 7    price

**Page 2:**

- meat type 8    price
- meat type 9    price

*Fish*

- fish type 1    price
- fish type 2    price
- the rest...

Each one is represented by a `LinearLayout` element containing name, price or just name in case of the tile.

I want to implement the `ViewPager` in a way that if I add another type of meat, it would add just below the `Fish` title and move the whole menu "down"(and maybe creating another page in the end in case it is necessary). Is it possible to achieve using a `ViewPager`?

Comment: Not an answer but ... on your place i would choose tabs(with viewpager frm support lib) as categories and listview on each page as menu items)

Comment: @Paulo-Barros I noticed that you've accepted the answer, but you didn't award the bounty. Just wanted to mention that you can give the bounty to the same answer as you accepted, or to a different one. But if you don't award it, half of it will automatically be given to the most popular answer, and half will be gone: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to implement the Viewpager in a way that if I add another type
>   of meat, it would add just below the Fish title and move the whole
>   Menu "down" (and maybe creating another page in the end in case it is
>   necessary). Is it possible to achieve using a Viewpager?

It's possible and pretty easy to make. You'll need to put all the data in the same list(so that list has all the types of items, titles and various food pieces). That list you'll break in sets according to the current position of the `ViewPager` . When you need to add a new item, insert it at the correct position in the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ViewPager`'s adapter(which will need a small change) to refresh the data and also update the pages if needed.

I've written a simple sample on how you might do this. You can find it [here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/dp/view/ViewPagerAdapt.java) as it is a little to big to post here. It should be self explanatory but don't hesitate to ask if you have problems.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is really simple and is exactly what I was looking for. But your link is broken, can you fix it? Thank you

Comment: @PauloBarros I've retested the link and it works, pointing to the project on github(on my account `github.com/luksprog`) where I uploaded the sample. But, if you still can't access it(or other problems) let me know and I will update my answer with the relevant parts from that code.